# Обнулить старшие разряды

Tags: ассемблер

Даны два числа в двоичном виде. В первом числе старшие (4 разряда) разряды обнулить. Во втором числе сделать единицами 2,4,6 разряды.
С помощью каких операций/команд можно реализовать данные задачи не привязываясь к конкретным числам?

Comment: gcc -S поможет Вам.

    void v() {
      int x;
    
      x &= 0x0fffffff; // обнулить 4 старших
      x |= 0x54; // установить  2,4,6 разряды (считая с нуля).
    }
     
    gcc -S a.c
    cat a.s
    ....
 .cfi_startproc
 pushq %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
 .cfi_offset 6, -16
 movq %rsp, %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
 andl $268435455, -4(%rbp)
 orl $84, -4(%rbp)
 popq %rbp
 .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ....

 ret
 .cfi_endproc

Comment: @avp в вузовских задачах по ассемблеру редко оперируют int32

Comment: > В первом числе старшие (4 разряда) разряды обнулить.
Это зависит от того, сколько всего двоичных разрядов. Если 32, то and reg, 0FFFFFFFh, если же всего 8, то and reg, 0Fh, а если 16, то and reg, 0FFFh.

Установка 2,4,6 разрядов - or reg, 54h (константу 54h взял из комментария @avp, но вроде бы она правильная:)

Comment: вообще вроде можно же сдвигом влево(SHL)/вправо(SHR) обнулять или нет ?

Comment: @avp, это на чем?
@insolor, да 8 разрядов. Я уже думал о командах логических операций, но на сколько я понимаю они изменять и остальные 4 разряда.
@eicto, если через сдвиги то старшие сдвинуться на места младших,а мне надо не тронув младшие.

Comment: @RubyNub, на ассемблере логические операции битовые, так что and reg, 0Fh это как раз то что нужно. По поводу сдвигов - если использовать нециклический сдвиг, то если сдвинуть на 4 бита влево, старшие биты уйдут в "никуда", останется только сдвинуть обратно на 4 бита.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за разъяснения. Уж больно не далек я еще в этом.

Comment: @RubyNub, это (вывод gcc -S) получено на

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat /etc/issue
    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc --version
    gcc.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

но gcc Вы можете поставить и на кучу других систем.

Comment: @avp если кого-то пугает ассемблер в телефонно-телеграфном формате, можно к -S добавить ключ -masm=intel

Answer (score 1):

Если Ваши числа размером слово, то код будет выглядеть так:

```
; В ax Ваше первое число
and ah, 00001111b
; В bx Ваше второе число
or bl, 00101010b
```

Comment: А что разряды справа читаются ? Почему bl?

Comment: Разряды считаются слева на право. И начинаются с нуля)